# Clear an inline-block

Tags: css

How can I clear an inline-block?

Here is my html:

```
<p>Text 1</p>
<p>Text 2</p>
<p class="third">Text 3</p>
<p>Text 4</p>
```

My css makes each p tag an inline-block, which is used for layout, styling, margins and padding purposes.

For a responsive layout I now need Text 3 to clear onto the next line, and for Text 4 to go with it. So before I had this:

Text 1 Text 2 Text 3 Text 4

But now I need this:

Text 1 Text 2

Text 3 Text 4

UPDATE - is there a solutin that doenst add extra HTML markup?

Comment: You don't need to clear, infact you can't clear inlineblocks, and inline blocks wrap themselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `float: left;` rather than `display: inline-block;` then you would be easily clear the `.third`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/clink/hdZXj/)

Answer (score 4):

A different approach, without muddling the HTML:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) {
  p {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
  p:nth-child(even) {
    clear: right;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  p {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/ALAYAlo/1/edit ( resize the output window )

Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/CFNyrom.png

Comment: I need the paragraphs to be in 2 rows, not 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<p>Text 1</p>
<p>Text 2</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p>Text 3</p>
<p>Text 4</p>
```

In CSS:

```
.clear{
   clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css.

```
   p{
    float:left;
    margin-right:3%   /*For spacing on between paragraph*/
}
.third{
    clear:left;
}
```